# Why the regular expression of /^Apple$/ only match string "Apple"?

Tags: regex, perl

I see the description of a book ...

The book say `/^Apple/` will match the string have a Apple in the beginning of the string .
So it will match `Apple Apple1 AppleApple AppleABC` ......

The book also say `/Apple$/` will match the string have a Apple in the end of the string .
So it will match `ABCApple 12345Apple` such like that ....

But the book say `/^Apple$/` will match only `Apple` . but I am confused , I think `/^Apple$/` should match the string which has the beginning of string "Apple" and the end of string "Apple" , so something like `AppleabcApple` should match , so I am confused .

Comment: What language are you implementing your regular expression in? Different programming languages have different rules and features for regular expressions.

Comment: @zzzzBov perl programming language

Comment: Your book is wrong. `/Apple$/` will match two things: 1) `Apple` at the end of a string, and 2) `Apple<newline>` at the end of a string.

Comment: Saying `/Apple$/` would match `Apple<newline>` at the end of a string might mislead people (regrettably I was one) that `s/Apple$/Pear/` for example would get rid of the newline. Probably be less ambiguous to say "match `Apple` before newline at the end of the string".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^` means the start of a string (or line, depending on your regex engine). `$` means the end of a string. Those are matched just like any letter or number, but match the "beginning" and "end" instead of a specific character.

So, `^Apple` means "Right after the beginning of the string, there must be a Apple". `Apple$` means "Right after `Apple` must be the end of the string". Thus, `^Apple$` means "After the beginning of the string is a Apple, and after that is the end of the string" -- thus, `^Apple$` can only match strings that contain exactly `Apple` and nothing else.

If you wanted to match a string beginning *and* ending with `Apple`, you could write

```
/^Apple.*Apple$/
```

(Things get more complicated if you want to match a string that can overlap itself, like `eraser` (e.g. matching `eraseraser`) -- if your regex engine allows it, you can try a mixed lookahead/lookbehind: `^(?=eraser).*(?<=eraser)$`)

Comment: I think /^Apple.Apple$/ is same as /^Apple.*Apple$/ . Is that right?

Comment: No. `Apple.Apple` matches `Apple`, followed by one character that's not a newline, followed by `Apple`. `Apple.*Apple` matches `Apple`, followed by any number of characters that aren't newlines, followed by `Apple`.

Comment: @ikegami Because /^Apple./ can match something like AppleAAAAA , so I misunderstand that . can represent any number of characters .....

Comment: no, The `.` is only matching the first "A". Does `AppleAAAA` have a start of string followed by `A` followed by `p` followed by `p` followed by `l` followed by `e` followed by any non-newline character? Yes, so it matches.

Comment: `/^Apple./` is not matching "AppleAAAAA", it's finding a valid match within "AppleAAAAA" by matching "AppleA".

Comment: To be clear you should say .* matches any number of characters (except newline), INCLUDING ZERO characters. To require at least one character use .+

Answer (score 7):

Instead of thinking of `^` and `$` as matching words at the start or end of a string, respectively, think of `^` and `$` as invisible characters that are at the start and end of strings, which you can match in regular expressions.

Searching for `apple$` means you are looking for the string `apple` followed immediately by the end-of-string "character". And a similar concept for `^`.

Therefore, to match `^apple$`, the start of the string has to be immediately *before* 'apple', and the end has to be immediately *after* 'apple'.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to match a string that either starts with Apple or ends with Apple then use this regex:

```
/^Apple|Apple$/
```

Comment: Why any parens at all? `/^Apple|Apple$/`. (And if you did need parens, it would be `...(?:^Apple|Apple$)...`. `(...)` are captures.) Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for removing parenthesis, don't know what I was thinking while adding those extra brackets :)

Answer (score 3):

The descriptions you were given for those regular expressions are a bit misleading.

`/^Apple/` *will* match any string that begins with "Apple", but that's because the pattern is the beginning of the string (`^`) followed immediately by a capital `A`, followed immediately by a lowercase `p`, etc.

Likewise, `/Apple$/` *will* match any string that ends with "Apple", but that's because the pattern is the literal string of "Apple" followed immediately by the end of the string.

What this means is that `/^Apple$/` is the beginning of the string, followed immediately by the literal string "Apple" followed immediately by the end of the string.

Because of this, there is no room in the pattern for matching anything else. If there were some wildcard characters, such as:

```
/^App.*le$/
```

you could match any string beginning with "App" and ending with "le" with a large variety of characters between them (`.` doesn't match *everything*, but it matches many characters).

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the two anchors (begin and end), that means "string must be exactly ..." (Apple, in your case).
To match the string at the beginning, you can use Perrenoud's formula or just `/^Apple`